# How to batch convert HTML web page links to MS- Word (doc) format?

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, batch, conversion

I have a list of around 153 URLs that I need to visit and save in editable MS-Word format. I have tried

1. converting the individual pages to pdf and then converting them to word format, and
2. converting individual pages directly to doc format (using a chrome extension)

But the method listed above in (2) doesnt convert the pages in batch. I have to manually visit each page and then save the page as a doc file. I need to automate it (convert links in batch) so that I can do some other productive work while this task is in progress. The page size and other parameters of the resulting file dont matter to me.

Comment: Have you tried using this: https://www.docverter.com/learn/

Comment: @RaghuRanganathan , I am currently working on a Windows machine and will have to wait till eod to get the above package running on my linux system.

Comment: Here's a starting point which you can fully integrate PowerShell execution into a batch just fine: `Invoke-WebRequest "https//www.website.com" -OutFile "C:\folder\file.html"` and then from there you see if you can convert from [HTML to PDF](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Convertto-PDFFile-dda02118)..... or use whatever method you can find, test, and confirm.